# How to run a *ngFor loop inside other loops

Tags: arrays, angular, split, ngfor, ionic5

I get a lot of data coming from an API, and among that data, I have these images:
Photos: "uploads/60bcb8f0244b2.png,uploads/60bcb8f025427.png"

I used *ngFor to present all the data that exists, "Photos" is one of them. My question is, how can I separate the link from this "Photos" field? Note that it currently has a comma separator. I can't use split(',') inside *ngFor. What would be the solution?

Comment: i can't understand what you mean , can you please give more details ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try split(",") as below

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of data">
    {{item.text}}
    <div *ngFor="let p of item.photos.split(',')">
      {{p}}
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is example for you: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-i92axf?file=src/app/app.component.html